# Stuck on Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, usb-debugging

I am trying to run my application on my physical device, and I am either getting an

```
> Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly.

Error launching application on V2036.
```

or else I am stuck on Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...  for like an eternity
The was able to run the application without any issues on my device without any issues before I updated my phone's OS which is Funtouch OS 13 Global

**I have tried using**
`flutter clean`, `./gradlew` clean but nothing is working because I think the issue is with my phone
I have turned off USB debugging and turned it on back again, I have tried restarting my phone
I run out of solutions can anyone tell me what can I do with my phone to make this work this is working fine on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a VIVO phone, they do have problems with USB debugging. I also had the same, at the start I wasn't able to debug at all, but after the update, it worked. You can wait for the next update or do the following that may work.

1. Use the original data cable, sometimes due to the local cable the USB debugging won't work. It happens in redmi phones usually.
2. You can also try the wireless debugging that comes in android studio, go to the device manager on android studio-->select the physical device and then at the top of that menu you'll see wireless debugging and follow the steps.